# "The possibility I am going to lose is low." instead of "There is a low possibility I am going to lose"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction

Can I say "The possibility I am going to lose is low." or "There is a low possibility of loss for me" or "The possibility of loss is low for me" instead of "There is a low possibility I am going to lose"?

Comment: We say "gonna".  We don't usually write "gonna".  In general, write "going to" --  *unless* you are trying to mimic some dialect.

Comment: Ok, I changed it. Since I usually say "gonna", I had written as "gonna".

Comment: In casual communication you can write whatever you like, "enuf", "thru", "tho", "c u l8tr"  and so on.  But these sound *informal* and are usually inappropriate in any context where you want to sound like a mature adult.

Comment: Ok thanks. Don't you have answer for my question? :) (Is it wrong to put smileys too?)

Comment: Aside from what you are asking, you should use the word "probability", rather than "possibility". Possibility means being possible (and not impossible), it is either true or false, and can't be "low".

Comment: @laugh it's a good point, and you are correct.  However I think many native speakers use "possibility" in this way, even if it is not *technically* the right word.

Comment: Do you agree with him on the matter of saying "losing" instead of "loss" too?

Comment: We do not say "gonna" unless being informal with friends. I say "going to" all the time.

Comment: All of your examples sound the same to me; just different ways to say the same thing.

Comment: Are you a native speaker? I like saying gonna better. It feels more natural when I say "gonna". This is out of topic though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between "losing" and "loss".  "Loss" generally refers to *misplacing* or otherwise losing *possession* of something, more often than it refers to something like losing a game.

> She is upset at the **loss** of her favorite ring.

You can talk about the *loss* of a game, but in your example you should say "a loss".

> There is a low possibility of a loss for me.

Otherwise, all of your examples are fine, just awkward and artificial.  More common expressions might be:

> I don't think I'm going to lose.
>
> I'm not likely to lose.
>
> There's only a slim possibility that I will lose.

You can also use *chance* instead of *possibility*:

> There's almost no chance I will lose.
>
> The chances of me losing are slim to none.

As well as many other expressions

Answer (score 0):

Let's first distinguish between **possibility** and **probability**, and between **loss** and **losing**.

The *possibility* of an event is related to the answer to the question "is it possible?", which can be either *yes* or *no*. This is a binary value (can also be described as true/false or 1/0). If you ask "what's the possibility of winning" the likely answer is "it is possible".

What you are actually interested in is the *probability* of an event, which is the answer to the question "how probable is it?". Without going into too much math, the probability of an event is a number between 0 (impossibility) and 1 (certainty), typically expressed as a percentage. For example, winning a single "heads or tails" toss of a fair coin has a probability of 50%.

*Losing* and *loss* are related terms with similar characteristics: when you make a bet or an investment, "losing" describes the event that you lose (which is eventually a binary value - you either lose or not), and "loss" describes how much you lose (which is a number or an amount of property). The corresponding terms for the case you win are "winning" and "gain".

Having clarified the terms, let's examine the sentences you suggested.
If you change "possibility" to "probability" and "loss" to "losing", you would get syntactically correct sentences, with slightly different emphasis. The choice may depend on the context.

1. **The probability [that] I am going to lose is low** - This is the most natural one, and the one you should normally use.
2. **There is a low probability of losing for me** would make sense if followed by **, *but not for you***.
3. **The probability of losing is low for me**  would make sense if followed by **, *but high for you***.

Here are some other possible sentences, using "possibility" and/or "loss":

4. The probability of your loss exceeding $100 is low *(e.g. if you invest your money, you may decide to sell your stock when the loss reaches $80)*.
5. The possibility of losing always exists *(e.g. if you make a "safe investment", your return may be lower than the inflation rate)*.
6. There is no possibility that your loss exceeds $1000 *(e.g. if you only invested $1000)*.

Comment: You don't agree with Andrew then? I searched and it seems that "high possibility" can be used. I had searched about it before as well. Also why do you think that I should use "losing" instead of "loss"? "Losing" doesn't sound wrong to me but also "loss" doesn't sound bad either to me.

Comment: "High/low possibility" is extremely uncommon compared to "high/low probability" as [Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=high+possibility%2Chigh+probability%2Clow+possibility%2Clow+probability&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chigh%20possibility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chigh%20probability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clow%20possibility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clow%20probability%3B%2Cc0) show.

Comment: Regarding *loss* vs. *losing*: the argument here is related, but different. I will expand the answer.

Comment: "High possibility" is wrong. Being wrong doesn't mean it isn't used. People, including native English speakers, often use wrong words.